# upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure | GRPC web Envoy

Tags: grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I am facing this error with envoy proxy :

`upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure` | 503 service unavailable.

This is my envoy.yaml

```yaml
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9000 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route:
                  cluster: position_service
                  max_grpc_timeout: 0s
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                - prefix: "*"
                allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                max_age: "1728000"
                expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
          - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
  - name: position_service
    connect_timeout: 2s
    type: logical_dns
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: cluster_0
      endpoints:
        - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: localhost
                    port_value: 3000
```

I already to remove http2_protocol_option. It didn't worked.
My GRPC client and server are in different container, same network.
I also tried to connect to my grpc server with a Go client and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mess up with the endpoint address. I replace localhost with the name of my container and I rebuilt my container after that because the file was copied to the container thanks to my dockerfile.